# AirDrop: Problem with previous file sender

Tags: macos, airdrop

The story is like this:

File was trying to be sent via Airdrop, I can't receive the file, both of us were on the Airdrop window, nothing happens. Quit the connection. Days later, Airdrop still shows the sender (friend) whom isn't even around the proximity and has jammed up my AirDrop.

Anybody knows how to resolve this issue? Refer to screenshot for problem.[image: Cannot view my own bubble.]